# Как Spring понимает что вызов метода это не создание нового объекта, а bean?

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, spring-boot

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public InMemoryUserDetailsManager userDetailsService() {
        UserDetails user1 = User.withUsername("user1")
            .password(passwordEncoder().encode("user1Pass"))
            .roles("USER")
            .build();
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user1);
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .failureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler())
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationFailureHandler authenticationFailureHandler() {
        return new CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

Comment: Грубо говоря spring вклинивается и перехватывает вызовы методов помеченные `@Bean` и при вызове такого метода он смотрит создан ли уже бин и если так, то использует его, иначе создает новый объект и регистрирует в контексте.

Comment: Из документации [Further Information About How Java-based Configuration Works Internally](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-java-further-information-java-config)